# Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY - is there a way to get the gravity value (9.8)?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I can't find the way of reaching the gravity value itself, only the x, y, z values that are not close to 9.8.
Probably I'm missing something.
I want to do something simple - display the gravity value in TextView.

in my main activity in onCreate() method I have:

```
gravityView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gravity);
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorGravity =  mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY).get(0);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorGravity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Then I override the onSensorChanged method:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()){
             case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:

                float alpha = 0.8f;
                float x, y, z;

                gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
                gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
                gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

                x = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
                y = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
                z = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

                double gravity = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) + Math.pow(z, 2));
                gravityView.setText("GRAVITY= " + gravity + "\n" + x + "\n " +  y + "\n " + z );

                break;
          }
    }
```

But the values in gravity, x, y and z are not close to 9.8.
Can somebody explain me what I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: I think I found the answer but I'm not sure, so I'm leaving the question open to get more qualified answer. double gravity = event.values[2];

Comment: answer it once you get solution